# MULE 4 Cookie Store

Tags: mule, acumatica, anypoint-studio

I am trying to connect my MULE Application to Acumatica. First, I have to send a login request to acumatica with username and password. Acumatica will send cookies in the response header. Now whenever I have to send a request to acumatica, I need to send the cookie with the request. How can I achieve this in Anypoint studio 7.2?

Answer (score -1):

If you are using an http endpoint, you can add a parameter in the connector, choose a header, then put the put the authorization in there. When it hits the endpoint, it will use this header.

Comment: Can you please explain in detail?

Comment: Not sure how else to explain it really. I'm assuming you are using an http connector to send your request. To set it up, you need to fill out the proper protocol, host, port, and Base Path in the configurations, then you want to set your path and method. Underneath all that, you can put authorization headers under the parameters section. You should be able to do what you are trying here.

Comment: For Authorization, I have to send cookies. I want to ask how to store the cookies I have received after sending a login request to acumatica and then use those cookies when sending other requests to acumatica.

Comment: Here is the mule doc explaining this: https://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/3.3.0/apidocs/org/mule/transport/http/CookieHelper.html

Comment: There is no class with name CookieHelper in Mule 4